# ActiveX => Blob

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I'm not a coder and need to do something simple,
I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this:
I have a function that returns an array, it works fine:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function WriteToFile() 
    {
       var fso, s;
       fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
       s = fso.OpenTextFile("exported.csv" , 2, 1, -2);
       var colvals = tf_table1.GetFilteredData(true);
       for (i=0; i<colvals.length; i++){
         s.write(colvals[i] + '\r\n');
     }
       s.Close();
    }
```

The only problem with it is that it needs the IE settings to be set on Minimum, as the CSV file is saved straight to Desktop, without asking the user.

Someone on stackoverflow has recommended using msSaveOrOpenBlob to me. I can't do any coding, but I tried my best... :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){

    $('#downloadButton').click(function () {
        var colvals = tf_table1.GetFilteredData(true);
        var blob = new Blob([ colvals ], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
        var filename = $('#fileName').val();

        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename); 
        }
        else {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = filename;
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.click();
            if (a.remove) a.remove();
        }
    });

    });//]]>  

    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <input id='fileName' type='text' value='My File.csv' />

    <br />
    <button id='downloadButton' draggable='true'>Save!!</button></body
```

>

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out!
Thanks

Comment: Thank you kind man! You saved the day. Much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, you should have put as an answer so I could vote it :-)

Comment: Mr Anonymous: Good job! Thanks. I have one more question if you don't mind:
Currently when I export my file it opens up as a very messy one: Some cells have a lot of text with commas, semicolons, and colons. Basically since this is a CSV, it picks them up (weirdly enough not only commas, but also ";" and ":" and sometimes even spaces!) and makes a new row each time. I tried to avoid this by putting quotes on both sides, but it looks a bit ugly in the actual html table. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not really, I already have a table which has around 2,000 entries, some of which contain sentences with commas. I can however do Find all > Replace, as another option. Any reason why with the initial code (ActiveX one) used only commas as delimiters, whereas your code also picks up semicolons and other characters? I thought when extracted, the files should look the same.

Comment: I'm using ordinary (7-bit?) text. I tried both of your solutions - neither of them seemed to help, I get the same extract again. Anyway, I guess I will just use the quotes, shouldn't be much of a problem, other than that it doesn't look good. Thank you for your contribution, you've been a great help!

Comment: Sure!
Original:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lr8tzsa4wbc3wf/Untitled.png?dl=0
ActiveX:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/31z8befz0r3ix1j/activex.csv?dl=0
Blob:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kasabugxt0zbwl3/blob_example.csv?dl=0
I had to blank some things out, but you get the gist of it

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I did temper with them a bit. 
The only thing I did with them now is replaced some of the cells with XXX as I don't want them to be on the Internet:
ActiveX: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtf17kxgvbkohni/activex.csv?dl=0
Blob:https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xgo4oytuh2628p/blob.csv?dl=0
Again, much appreciated for your invaluable help!

Comment: Also, the getfiltereddata function returns some value in column 1 which is not in the actual html table, think it is the row number - is it possible to get rid of it? I think it is "rowindex" in the getfiltereddata() function is in my post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856649/avoid-activex-to-save-a-file

Comment: You need only one file if I understand correctly?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/isrxenxoxh4js8u/MyJSONcsv.txt?dl=0

Comment: That's perfect!!! I can't thank you enough ... :-)

Comment: r1[j]= '"'+r1[j].replace('"','""')+'"' // if there is any " already inside field string, it needs to be doubled.  per csv rfc.

Is this working for you? This is what I get when I have " inside field string:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xh43e99wp7knddj/quotes_example.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3l4g7qx2b4pyl2s/MyJSONcsv.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sd0thr4ezfr8e4/example.png?dl=0
Weirdly enough it's fine for the title which has quotes, but not for the package overview.

Otherwise, I didn't notice any bugs.

Comment: Also, one small bug - "–" sign is exported as " â€“ " for some reason. UTF-8?

Comment: Ok, I will try to play with it, see if it works. 
Sure thing, that's perfectly understandable, good luck to you, and much appreciated.

Comment: Mr Anonymous: Not sure if you will use this website anymore, but just FYI, here's how I fixed this:

Replace 

    var blob = new Blob([ colvals ], 

with

    var blob = new Blob(["\uFEFF" + buffer], 

and 

 

    r1[j]= '"'+r1[j].replace('"','""')+'"'

with
 

    r1[j]= '"'+r1[j].replace(/"/g, '""')+'"'